# WPF. Реализация ластика на Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать ластик на Canvas?
Я пытаюсь реализовать небольшое приложение для рисования поверх экрана. Сам Canvas прозрачный.
Пытался получать цвет background канваса и его прозрачность. Но эффекта ластика не было, было просто рисование еле видным цветом Canvas. InkCanvas не подходит.

Comment: У каждого цвета в WPF есть альфа-канал, уровень его прозрачности. Например `#FF0000` или `#FFFF0000`- это красный, а `#00FF0000` - это прозрачный, ну или красный с 100% прозрачностью. Такой формат задания цвета называется ARGB (Alpha-Red-Green-Blue). Вам просто нужен прозрачный цвет.

Comment: пробовал, это не помогает. Либо не так пробовал, если вы уверены что это должно работать)

Comment: Получается, я ошибся и подумал про растровое рисование. А вы наверное рисуете в векторе. Следовательно, стереть не получится, только удалять нарисованные объекты. Например, нарисовали линию, можно ее целиком потом удалить, оставив остальное. Если же вам нужна растровая графика, где рисование идет изменением цвета пикселей, то ищите другой способ рисовать, не `Canvas`. Там можно будет стирать с помощью прозрачного цвета.

Comment: Ну либо использовать белый к приемеру фон, и стирать просто рисуя белым.